# Can not access IIS7 website externally - but can locally

Tags: iis

I have 2 websites, site A running on port 80 and site B configured to run on port 8080.

I can access site A no problem, but site B I can only access from the local web server machine. Externally it is not accessable, I have tried the url and ip and neither work. I have tried different configuring on port 8081 as a test and that didnt work either.

What IIS settings should I look at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd want to look at all of the bindings for the site - however if you can access ok locally but not remotely you're probably hitting a firewall issue somewhere.  Have you checked all firewalls are allowing port 8080 inbound?

Comment: Oops - it was the firewall aonly allowing port 80 and 443. Working now.